# Using ggplot to plot a map from a matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to create some maps by using ggplot2, but I am struggling to find the best way. Since I have a list ("models") with matrix, I wanted to use ggplot because then, it should be easier to create a multiplot (with facet_wrap..but just a thought).
I will create an reproducible example for doing this:

```
#European corrdinates
lon <- rep(loni,38)  #longitude values -13W-34E
lat <- rep(lati, each = 48)  #latitude values 34N-70N
#Matrix of values
mod <- matrix( rnorm(48*38,mean=0,sd=1), 48, 38)
#Create a list of matrix (as my real data)
dat.mod <- rep(list(mod), 4)
names(dat.mod) <- c("DJF","MAM","JJA","SON")

#Order data
md <- melt(dat.mod)
md$lon <- lon
md$lat <- lat
md$group <- "Model1"
names(md) <- c("X1","X2","SI","Season","lon","lat","model")
#
#First try: 
#Problem here: I don't know how to add the map
  brks <- seq(0, 2.2, by=0.2)
 cols <- colorRampPalette(c("skyblue1", "lightcyan2", "lightyellow",   "yellow", "orange", "red3"))(length(brks)-1)
 m <- ggplot(data = md, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = SI)) + 
 geom_raster() +
 scale_fill_gradientn(colours = cols, na.value = NA)+
 facet_wrap(~ model~ Season, nrow =11,ncol=4)+
 theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
 strip.text.x = element_blank())
 #I would get this image:
```

[image]

#Now, as a second try to add a map of Europe, I used:
     map <- ggplot()
     map <- map + coord_fixed()
     map <- map + geom_polygon(data=map_data(map="world"), aes(x=long, y=lat,   group=group), fill=NA, color="black", size=0.01)
     map <- map + coord_cartesian(xlim=range(md$lon), ylim=range(md$lat))
     map <- map + geom_tile(data=md, aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill=SI), alpha=I(0.7))
     map <- map + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=cols)
     map <- map + facet_grid(model~Season)
     map <- map + theme(legend.position="none")

Now, I would have:
 [image]

The problem with the second one is that I don't know how to change to background with white, and make the map more visible..is that possible?? The thing is, I wanted to plot 11 rows by 4 col. so when plotting all together it doesn't look very well...any suggestion?

Really appreciate any help.

Many thanks

Comment: Is [this](http://www.milanor.net/blog/maps-in-r-plotting-data-points-on-a-map/) in the ballpark? There are many other posts like this... basically, read in a map and then overplot. There's also [ggmap](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/kahle-wickham.pdf), and I gave a talk with some basics on geospatial plotting you can look at [here](https://github.com/jwhendy/devFest-geo). Sorry if this completely misses the mark... it sounded like you could make the lat/lon plot and now just want the map as your background canvas?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I can get any ideas from that..but I am not sure if I can use ggmap here (or I don't know how to do it).If I have my own coordinates for the map (almost all Europe) , can I plot the map? or do I need to get the shapes from anywhere? Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like you updated the question; it wasn't clear that "map" meant tile map? Or is this just a way to represent the dataset? I guess I'm still not clear what you're looking for... if you can post the actual data (maybe dump the raw `.csv` on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or something) that would help a lot. Alternatively can you fake maybe just 10 data points and draw a mockup of what you want? Like dots on geographical locations shown on an EU map, for example (that's what I had in my head).

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear..I just updated my question with the maps that I get so far (only with my data, let's say that they represent a meteorological variable) . I just wanted to find a way to add the map of Europe over those plots (that represent my dataset). So, I was wondering, if I have the coordinates of latitude and longitude, how to do it..does it sound clearer? thanks anyway!

Comment: Not really that much clearer to me... you have a sort of heat map looking thing in a box bounded by min/max lat and lon. A country would either be entirely contained in that, fully outside of it, or overlap it at points. Take a look at [this map of USA with lat/lon](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/usa/activity/latlong/map.GIF). Would your colored squares above just fill in certain quadrants? A picture is worth a thousand words. Like I said, just fake it. Any attempt at illustration will be clearer. Your real data would make it much easier to try and replicate something for you.

Comment: Also, the talk I referenced in first comment shows how to grab a country map and overplot... so if you have a matrix of lats/lons and color values... from what I know it sounds like you could bring that in and then overplot with your values.

Comment: Thanks for the comments..sorry for my late answer. I just edited my question, and I faked my example. I attached my try. Many thanks again.